# How do I make this python app installable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

My goals:

- Make a python app
- Have it pip installable directly from github
- After install, be able to run the app like: python -m myhelloapp

What I have done so far:

- I created a project "projectname" on github and cloned it to my computer
- I made a small test app with Python 3.6.1:

.

```
x@F:~/projects/projectname$ pwd
/home/x/projects/projectname

x@F:~/projects/projectname$ tree
.
|-- LICENSE.txt
`-- myhelloapp
    |-- app.py
    `-- __main__.py
```

.

```
x@F:~/projects/projectname$ cat myhelloapp/__main__.py

import app

def main():
    helloapp = app.HelloApp()
    helloapp.hello()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

.

```
x@F:~/projects/projectname$ cat myhelloapp/app.py

class HelloApp:

    def hello(self):
        print ("Hello!")
```

.

```
x@F:~/projects/projectname$ python myhelloapp
Hello!
```

Ok, now I need to configure the pip setup. How do I do it?

EDIT:

I am capable of finding lots of information with google. It just seems that nothing seems to match this problem exactly, and I would have to post 10 more questions for every possible error message that I have encountered so far. That's why I'm asking with this simple example project. If you are here to downvote or just post links (without comment) to something I've already read, please go away and do something more positive and constructive with your day.

Comment: http://marthall.github.io/blog/how-to-package-a-python-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=register_form

create a username and password and 
click link in "Complete your PyPI registration" email
(you don't need the "PGP Key ID" unless you want it)

in top level directory `projectname` create file named:

`setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='myhelloapp',      # name of PyPI package
    version='0.1',          # version number, update with new releases
    packages=['myhelloapp'] # names of packages directories
)
```

or instead of packages, for files use:

```
files=['myhelloapp.py']    # name of scripts
```

create a file named:

`.pypirc`

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi

[pypi]
username: your_username
password: your_password
```

run this:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

install twine:

```
pip install twine
```

and run these two lines:

```
twine upload dist/myhelloapp-0.1-py2-none-any.whl
twine upload dist/myhelloapp-0.1.tar.gz
```

enter username and password when prompted

now your package should be available via:

```
pip install myhelloapp
```

Comment: Thanks! This works after I changed "import app" to "from myhelloapp import app".